# Proving $x^{nm}-c$ irreducible $\leftrightarrow x^n-c,x^m-c$ irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I've proven the implication $\rightarrow$ so far but I'm out of ideas for $\leftarrow$. I tried to find an approach using Eisenstein's criterion but haven't had much luck.

$x^n-c,x^m-c,x^{nm}-c \in K[x]$ for arbitrary Field $K$

Comment: In an arbitrary field?

Comment: How did you prove the $\to$ direction?

Comment: Yes, added this information now. Good point since I can't use Eisenstein's in an arbitrary Polynomial Ring.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Assume that $x^n-c$ is reducible than $\exists f,g$ with degree $< n$ such that $x^n-c = f(x)g(x)$ but $x^{mn}-c = (x^m)^n-c \rightarrow x^{mn}-c = f(x^m)g(x^m)$ the degrees of which are obviously $< mn$ so $x^{mn}-c$ is reducible which is a contradiction

Comment: @user844177 Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the condition $gcd(m,n)=1$ we get following proof. Let $d\in\overline K$ such that $d^{mn}-c=0$. Then we have the field $L_{mn}:=K(d)$ and subfields $L_m:=K(d^n); L_n:=K(d^m)$. Here we get the equivalence:

$X^{mn}-c$ is irreducible iff $[L_m\cdot L_n :K]= [L_{mn}:K]=mn$ iff $[L_m:K]=m \land [L_n:K]=n$ iff $X^{m}-c$, $X^{n}-c$ are irreducible.

**counterexample for gcd(m,n)>1:** Choose $m=n=2$ and $K=\mathbb{R}$. Then $X^2+1$ is irreducible but $X^4+1$ is reducible.